# Does WebKit use OpenGL to render CSS transitions?

Tags: opengl, css, webkit, css-transitions

Does WebKit use OpenGL to render CSS transitions, or does it use software rendering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WebKit is just a frontend. It depends on the backend and the hardware support. Google Chrome uses [skia](http://code.google.com/p/skia/) as a back-end and it can use software or hardware. So the answer is it depends on the implementation of the back-end and the hardware it is running on.

Answer (score 3):

From what I know the only hardware accelerated property using transitions is the `translate3d` `transform`.

Eg:

```
// Normal
div{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

// Adding class to animate
div.transformed{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px, 100px, 0);
}
```

If you use just the `translate` transform or animate any other property it won't be hardware accelerated.

Comment: I should note that this is true for Safari/Mobile-Safari, some other implementations might not be HW accelerated at all or have better support for it.

Comment: All transitions are HW accelerated (using OpenGL) in Safari regardless of the property/transform. You can see that because of initial flickering & different font rendering in certain circumstances. Also, the transitions couldn't so smooth especially in Mobile Safari if HW acceleration was not used.

Comment: Actually there's evidence that hardware acceleration is only used with `translate3d` and not with `translate`, one of the reasons for this difference is because translate was implemented in Safari a lot sooner than translate3d.

Comment: There are some webpages that make reference to the difference in performance between these two: [link](http://mir.aculo.us/2010/06/04/making-an-ipad-html5-app-making-it-really-fast/), [link](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) search for `translate3d`, [link](http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/having-fun-with-css-keyframes/). I've tested this and the difference is noticeable specially on iOS, although hw-acceleration is kind of buggy and uses more resources.

Comment: Thanks Mario. The links are partly outdated (the first one mentioning IOS 3.0), though no doubt I was oversimplifying above. I think we can safely assume that in most (webkit) platforms most of the stuff is HW accelerated, and it's getting better all the time.

Comment: No problem, yes HW acceleration is being implemented slowly, although some of them are very buggy or have issues on mobile devices because of limited resources. I had to change most `translate3d` transitions on a web app because it had visual glitches on iOS 5, some elements were being rendered badly (pixelated). Sadly there's no precise documentation on HW acceleration for HTML and on what platforms it is being supported.